# Adding an event to a calendar from Flutter app

Tags: flutter

When user presses a button in my app, I want to save an event to the users calendar. By opening up an already filled calendar app. With Android to add an event to users calendar developer would use an Intent. How do accomplish this with Flutter?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235387/using-the-googleapis-library-in-dart-to-update-a-calendar-and-display-it-on-a-we
for flutter you can find apis here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis

Comment: @user1506630 have you found any solution?

Answer (score 10):

I had in the same situation as you and then I met [this library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_calendar).

Check it out and let me know!

Comment: There isn’t any documentation for this plugin

Comment: Thanks @TomStein , I found it and was able to get it working!

Comment: Thanks @TomStein !

Comment: Very useful plugin.It works.In iOS, the event is added in background.But, in android, calendar app will be opened, and user needs to save it.I need to save the event to calendar in background just like in iOS.Any help?

Comment: @SamCromer can you give me an example how you implement in flutter app. if yes then it's very helpful to me.

Comment: I still couldn't find the documentation. :( Can someone share the link? Maybe add it to the Readme even :)

Comment: @Throvn Check the example here: https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar/example

Answer (score 0):

See this [blog](https://morioh.com/p/7fcc4bfcc5bc) about adding event to device calender and didn't depend on any other packages.
the package name is [add_2_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar)

Comment: The link is broken, can you provide the correct link

Comment: No need you can see an example exists in this package @MarufHassan

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but i was struggling with this myself.
I was trying the device_calendar Package aswell as @Joaquin mentioned. But the lack of documentation bothered me and it seemed not like the thing i was trying to accomplish.

For my usecase it was enough to just use Android-Intents since i dont want to deploy the App on another Platform. The documentation for that is "weird" aswell, but i got it now.

I dont know if you need to have the READ/WRITE Intents, but for good measurement, add following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

Get the [android_intent_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus/example) flutter package. And then import following pacakge:

```
import 'package:android_intent_plus/android_intent.dart';
```

Finally the Code that was working for me was:

```dart
  void saveTheDate() {
    final intent = AndroidIntent(
      action: 'android.intent.action.INSERT', // Important
      data: 'content://com.android.calendar/event', // Important
      type: "vnd.android.cursor.dir/event", // Important
      arguments: <String, dynamic>{
        'title': event.title,
        'allDay': true,
        'beginTime': event.date?.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        'endTime': event.date?.millisecondsSinceEpoch ??
            DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch + 3600000 * 2,
        'description': event.description,
        'eventLocation': event.locationDescription,
        'hasAlarm': 1,
        'calendar_id': 1,
        'eventTimezone': 'Europe/Berlin'
      },
    );

    intent.launchChooser("Choose an App to save the Date");
  }
```

This will open a Device-Based Dialog to choose an app that can handle this Action (Google Cal, Huawei Cal, etc. [Outlook seems not to work tho :( ])
To read more about the Calendar Intent, i link the Android docs where you can see more Arguments you can set etc.: [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#AddEvent)

Any package like the [device_calender](https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar)-Plugin is doing (more or less) the same in the background, but for simpler cases where im already using other special intents and only need to save an event at one place this suits me better because i dont depend on a whole library.

Comment: how to use while app is in background/killed mode?